# Python program working fine in App Engine Standard Environment. But we get SSL error when we schedule it in App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

We have successfully executed the source data collection python program using App Engine Cron service in App Engine Flexible environment.

Now, We are trying to execute the same python program in App Engine Standard Environment. But, We are getting the Error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. 
Anyone came across this Error ? I have given full access to App Engine default service account for the Bucket. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add some code and the full error output to add some context.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this error.

We need to add the below libraries in the app.yaml

libraries:
 - name: ssl
   version: latest